# Correct use of equals syntax

Tags: php, comparison

could someone please help me with the following code

```
if ($scope = '9001') $docref = $rs["9001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope = '14001') $docref = $rs["14001ref"];
elseif ($scope = '18001') $docref = $rs["18001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope = '9001,14001') $docref = $rs["914001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope = '9001,18001') $docref = $rs["918001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope = '14001,18001') $docref = $rs["1418001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope = '9001,14001,18001') $docref = $rs["91418001ref"];
```

I am unsure if I should be using = or ==

and also unsure if I should be using ' ' or " "

Could someone please let me know and provide a brief explanation so I know going forward, thank you.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: There's not a lot of mysql going on here

Comment: RTFM: `=` is the assignment operator, `==` is for loose comparisons, `===` is type & value checking

Answer (score 2):

In comparison single `=` means you are assigning some value to variable. E.g. `$scope = '14001'` will assign `14001` to `$scope`. To compare something, use `==` (just if values are same) or `===` (if values and types match).
Using `'` versus `"` is basically code style matter. But if you are using some variables in string, than `"` will parse string to check if there is any variable inside, while `'` will ignore any variable inside string.
E.g.:

```
$scope = '123';

echo "My scope is {$scope}"; // will echo "My scope is 123";
echo 'My scope is {$scope}'; // will echo "My scope is {$scope}";
```

Also you can use any variable that starts with `$` in `"` wrapped string:

```
echo "Variable {$variable}";
echo "String {$row['someKey']}";
echo "Object {$this->variable}";
echo "Object method that returns value {$this->getValue()}";
```

Answer (score 0):

In comaprison there has to be `==`

```
if ($scope = '9001') $docref = $rs["9001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope == '14001') $docref = $rs["14001ref"];
elseif ($scope == '18001') $docref = $rs["18001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope == '9001,14001') $docref = $rs["914001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope == '9001,18001') $docref = $rs["918001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope == '14001,18001') $docref = $rs["1418001ref"]; 
elseif ($scope == '9001,14001,18001') $docref = $rs["91418001ref"];
```

For this case better solution is to use `switch` instead of `if-elseif` conditions.